# How to form `JSON` with positional values from a correlated DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` which looks like the one below.

```
                       A      B      C
Timestamp                               
2019-01-12 00:00:00  43.73  28.95  25.31
2019-01-12 00:15:00  44.08  29.34  25.25
2019-01-12 00:30:00  44.39  29.59  25.12
2019-01-12 00:45:00  44.34  29.48  24.96
2019-01-12 01:00:00  44.75  29.42  24.95
```

On finding the correlation for it, I get the following:

`df.corr()`

```
          A         B         C
A  1.000000  0.758167  0.859099
B  0.758167  1.000000  0.923995
C  0.859099  0.923995  1.000000
```

I want the result to be displayed in the json given below for plotting heatmap in the UI.

```
{
  "data": [
    [0,0,0.85],[0,1,0.93],[0,2,1],
    [1,0,0.75],[1,1,1],[1,2,0.92],
    [2,0,1],[2,2,0.75],[2,2,0.85],
  ],
  "category": ["A","B","C"]
}
```

How can I get the positional values and form a Json of lists from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think first is necessary change ordering of rows by indexing with `[::-1]` and then create nested lists in list comprehension with `enumerate`, last create dict by this list with columns names:

```
df1 = df.corr().iloc[::-1]

L = [[a, b, y] for a, (_,x) in enumerate(df1.items()) for b, y in enumerate(x)]
d = { "data": L, "category": df.columns.tolist()}
print (d)
{
    'data': [
        [0, 0, -0.8845563092588891],
        [0, 1, 0.7799764515321312],
        [0, 2, 1.0],
        [1, 0, -0.6854920251297654],
        [1, 1, 1.0],
        [1, 2, 0.7799764515321312],
        [2, 0, 1.0],
        [2, 1, -0.6854920251297654],
        [2, 2, -0.8845563092588891]
    ],
    'category': ['A', 'B', 'C']
}
```

Comment: @Irfanuddin - yop, not sure if `.iloc[::-1]` is necessary, but added because expected output. but maybe is necessary remove it.

Comment: It worked pretty well, Thanks again! I also found another way using `pandas.melt()`. We just have to rename the columns with the index and melt it. I'll share the code in an answer below.